# Naming a text file as a variable

Tags: php

I have a variable `$Date` that is automatically updated each day. I would like to create a new text file each time that there is a new entry. So basically every day.
I would like to use `fopen` to create a new text file every time a user submits a value, but only for that day. If a user creates another account the next day, it will be a new text file with that date for a name...

I only have three variables, `$date`, `$Name`, and `$number`

Is it possible to create this as follows?

```
$textmember = "$date.txt"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could easily create a new text file each day.

```
$filename = "$date.txt";
if (! file_exists($filename)) {
    $fp = fopen($filename,'w');
    //write stuff to file
    fclose($fp);
}
```

If you're appending data to the file, you don't even need to do the `file_exists()` check, you can just use the 'a' option of `fopen()`:

```
$filename = "$date.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename,'a');
//write stuff and close
```

In this case, the file will be created if it doesn't exist, and if it does, the data you write will just be appended on the end.

Comment: sorry to be a noob, but I cant  seem to get it to work with your second suggestion, here is my code, I think its just syntax errors, but it will not create a new file, it just says "no directory found"
    
    $filename = "data/textmembers/date/$Date.txt";
    $fp = fopen($filename,'a');
    fwrite($fp,$Name);
    fwrite($fp,$Number);
    fclose($fp);

Comment: Sounds like the directory you're trying to write to doesn't exist.  Make sure the path is correct.  If you use a relative path, it will be relative from the script that's being run.

Comment: Make sure you use the correct date format - if you have a special character like ` / ` or ` : ` in the date for `mm/dd/yyyy` or `hh:mm:ss` respectively, it might create problems. Use a date format like `yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss` or `yyyymmdd-hhmmss` or `yyyymmdd` and then append the `$name` and `$number` or whatever to it. The PHP manual should give you a simple way of specifying the date format.

Answer (score 1):

That should be as easy as

```
file_put_contents($filename, $text, FILE_APPEND);
```

where $filename should be a combination of $name and $date and $text the data you want to write. You only have to combine $data and $name if you want a file per name and date, e.g.

```
$filename = sprintf('%s-%s.txt', $date, $name);
```

So, with $date being 2009-12-30 and $name being Gordon you'd get `2009-12-30-Gordon.txt`. That file would be created if it does not already exist and $text would be written into it. If it already exists, $text would be appended into it, e.g.

```
$filename = sprintf('%s-%s.txt', date('Y-m-d'), 'Gordon'); // create filename
file_put_contents($filename, 'foo', FILE_APPEND); // create file and write to it

// later that day    
file_put_contents($filename, 'bar', FILE_APPEND);  // append to existing file
```

You have to make sure the directory you create the file in is writable.

Check the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can create the file with a especified format everyday and check if the file doesnt exists already, if it doesnt then create it. I would use the format $username-$date, so a file for the username ryudice would look like "ryudice-22-2-2009.txt", then you can check if the file exists every time the user submits a value, if it doesnt exist then create it, to check if the file already exists you can use the file_exists function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5+...

```
$filename = 'data/textmembers/date/' . $Date . '.txt';
file_put_contents($filename, $Name, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filename, $Number, FILE_APPEND);
```

If your script is located in /var/www/html/my_script.php then the file will be saved at /var/www/html/data/textmembers/date/$Date.txt .  You will need to make sure that directory (/path/to/date) has write permissions for the user PHP runs under.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was the date format, I just had to change it to 12-30-2009 instead of 12/30/2009